# How do I use a binary prefix in accordance with C11?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, standards, standards-compliance, c11

I am currently starting out with programming micro controllers using `C30` (A `C` compiler based on `GCC` from microchip for their `PIC24` devices) and I enabled `Strict ANSI warnings` out of curiosity. First off, I did not know that in C11 comment markings like // are "wrong" and instead I should use /* blah blah */, but what really surprised me is this warning for a line of code.

"warning: use of non-standard binary prefix"

The line of code is:

`OSCCONbits.COSC = 0b000;`

I have looked online at one of the drafts of C11 (ISO/IEC 9899:2011) and can't find anything about binary prefixes in C. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf

What is the correct binary notation for C according to C11?

Comment: Convert it to a hexadecimal number. As for setting something to (binary) `0000` why not just use a normal decimal `0` or hexadecimal `0x00`?

Comment: Who told you // comments are "wrong"?

Comment: I think I may have worded my question wrong, so here are some corrections. I know that I can just use hex or decimal instead of binary, I just wanted to know what was the "right" way to use binary literals. Regarding me saying // comments are "wrong", I got that from a compiler warning, no one told me that but the compiler. Anyways, thanks for all the help guys! I got some awesome answers and I wish I could mark them all as answers but I could do that to only one sadly.

Comment: @hak8or: then it was not a c99 or c11 compiler.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: To be completely pedantic, `0` is an *octal* constant, not decimal(!)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

C does not have binary constants. (Even in C11 they are not supported.)

They were proposed as an addition to C99 but the proposition was rejected.

From C99 Rationale document:

> A proposal to add binary constants was rejected due to lack of precedent and insufficient utility.

You said you are using a compiler based `gcc` and `gcc` supports binary constants: they are a GNU extension to the C language.

> Integer constants can be written as binary constants, consisting of a sequence of `0` and `1` digits, prefixed by `0b` or `0B`. This is particularly useful in environments that operate a lot on the bit-level (like microcontrollers).

See `gcc` page about binary constants for more information:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Binary-constants.html

Comment: Bummer they felt it wasn't of sufficient utility. I use `0b` all the time in code that does bit-twiddling for high-speed integer operations (having nothing to do with microcontrollers). `0b10101010` is much more readable to me than `0xAA`, for example. Also a bummer they felt there wasn't precedent; Java has had `0b` for a while now.

Answer (score 5):

Regarding standards:

- ANSI C / "Strict ANSI" typically refers to the first standard version of C, standardized only in the USA 1989. Sometimes it is referred to as "C89".
- ANSI C/89 became obsolete in 1990 when C became an international C standard, ISO/IEC 9899:1990, referred to as "C90". C89 and C90 are equivalent when it comes to technical details.
- C90 became obsolete in 1999, when ISO C was updated. The new standard is referred to as "C99".
- C99 became obsolete in 2011. The new standard is referred to as "C11".

Regarding your compiler problems:

- C89/C90 does not allow // comments. They were introduced in C99. They have not been removed in C11.
- Binary notation has never been part of any C standard.

Conclusion:

- You are most likely compiling the code on a C90 compiler, with some non-standard extensions available.

Answer (score 3):

C11 does not have binary literals; it only has decimal, octal, and hexadecimal, as described in section 6.4.4.1 of the standard.  This is unchanged from C99.

6.6 paragraph 10 says:

> An implementation may accept other forms of constant expressions.

which, if I understand it correctly, permits the kind of extension that your compiler provides; this is also unchanged from C99.

The usual workaround is to use hexadecimal literals; each hexadecimal digit corresponds to four binary digits.  (And of course `0b000` can be written simply as `0`.)

Comment: This is not a correct interpretation of C11§6.6p10. §6.6 is intended to carve out a subset of valid expressions that are guaranteed to evaluate to constants. It does not extend the parser or lexer (which would be needed to support binary literals).

Comment: @SamElliott I'm inclined to agree. I'll have to think about this a bit more. If you're right, it implies that binary literals can be supported as an extension under C11 4p6, but a conforming compiler must still issue a diagnostic for `0b000` because it violates a syntax rule.

Answer (score 2):

Binary prefixes are not standard. convert them to octal (`0`) or hexadecimal (`0x`) instead, which are only prefixes defined in the standard.

Also, `//` comments were introduced in C99 standard, they're not present in C89 ANSI standard. That's why your compiler gives you a warning.